# How to convert FileBytes into a File?

Tags: android, json

I am receiving following JSON response from the server for showing the file in my android project.

```
"FileBytes":"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",
```

As i am newbie , I am not understanding how to convert this into a file.
It can be a any type of file like xyz.jpeg,.png,.pdf...anything

Please help me.

Comment: so, basically it's an Image?

Comment: no, server can send any type of file .it cab be a image, a doc, xls, zip, dwg...anything

Comment: Since i as well as nobody in stackoverflow can do this hence server itself change the service to send the file not filebytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this type of conversion, hence server itself change the service to send the file not filebytes with some authentication.